# Array Buttons shows same text in text view, how to change?

Tags: android, arrays, button, textview

the following app code consists of buttons aligned as five in a row and totally six rows.
There are five buttons in a row namely one, two,three,four, five which are initialized through an array idArray.

now if i press button one , text "one" should be visible and if i press button two the text "one" should change to "two"

however in my code all the five buttons on press shows text as "one" only.

please go through my code and correct me, where iam wrong?

Heres the code

```
package com.example.numbers;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NumbersActivity extends Activity{

private static final int[] idArray = {R.id.bt0,R.id.bt1,R.id.bt2,R.id.bt3,R.id.bt4};
private Button[] bt = new Button[idArray.length];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numbers);

    TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    for (int i=0;i<idArray.length;i++){
        final int b = i;
        bt[b]= (Button)findViewById(idArray[b]); //Fetch the view id from array

    bt[b].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
        TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {

    case R.id.bt0:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.one));

            case R.id.bt1:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.two));

            case R.id.bt2:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.three));

            case R.id.bt3:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.four));

            case R.id.bt4:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.five));


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED
                    one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  return true; // if you want to handle the touch event

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED
                    one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  return true; // if you want to handle the touch event

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
  }

}

}
```

when i press bt1 text shows as one, but when i press bt2 text shows as "one" only, it should show "two" instead. 
Please help me with my code and tell me where's the mistake.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: case ->  break (or fallthrough)

Comment: how to arrange the `Switch` case?

Comment: use `break`, otherwise you fallthrough

Comment: you can't use `switch(event.getAction()) {` with `case R.id.bt1:` it makes no sense

Comment: I assume `one` is the default text of the textview?

Comment: `one` is defined as "one" in XML, i want to change it to "two" when bt1 is pressed.

Comment: then how to change the text to "two", when bt2 `Button` is pressed @njzk2

Comment: you can only compare `R.id.bt1` with a view's id, like `v.getId()`. You probably should use an OnClickListener for that, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With due respects to the comments above and silly mistakes pointed out by @Context, @user3676184, @ njzk2, i made suitable changes in my code to get what i wanted. 
Here's the working code below:

```
package com.example.numbers;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NumbersActivity extends Activity{

private static final int[] idArray = {R.id.bt0,R.id.bt1,R.id.bt2,R.id.bt3,R.id.bt4};
private Button[] bt = new Button[idArray.length];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numbers);

    TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    for (int i=0;i<idArray.length;i++){
        final int b = i;
        bt[b]= (Button)findViewById(idArray[b]); //Fetch the view id from array

    bt[b].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
        TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bt0:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.one));
                    break;
            case R.id.bt1:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.two));
                    break;
            case R.id.bt2:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.three));
                    break;
            case R.id.bt3:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.four));
                    break;  
            case R.id.bt4:
                one.setText(getString(R.string.five));
                    break;
            }
            switch(event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED
                    one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  return true; // if you want to handle the touch event

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED
                    one.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                  }  
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
  }

}

}
```

All i did was sorted my `switch` case by replacing `switch(event.getAction())` to `switch(v.getId())` to case statements of Buttons and adding `switch(event.getAction())` to case statements of `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and yes also i removed the `final` from `int i`

Now my app shows text as per the corresponding Button Touch. That's what i exactly wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the initialization of the variable `i` in your for loop as final and the final doesn't change, so remove the final like that or yous `i` directly

```
for (int i=0;i<idArray.length;i++){
    int b = i;
    bt[b]= (Button)findViewById(idArray[b]); //Fetch the view id from array
```

> In the Java programming language, the final keyword is used in several different contexts to define an entity which may only be assigned once.
>
> Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value

Comment: removing the final from `int b = i;` didnt help :(

Comment: don't forget to add `break` after each `case` as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: then too i removed the final from the line, as pointed by you.

Comment: added `break;` after each `case`

Comment: no. the `b` is scoped in the loop block and is therefore a different variable at every iteration

Answer (score 1):

After each case add `break` like this:

```
case R.id.bt1:
    one.setText(getString(R.string.two));
    break;
```

Comment: adding `break;` after each `case` didnt change the text as desired :(